# XNA - SoundEffect with SpeedOfSound

Tags: xna, monogame, sound-effects

SoundEffect has SpeedOfSound property. I'm trying to use it, but it doesn't work:

```
SoundEffect.SpeedOfSound = 600.0f;
SoundEffectInstance soundEffectInstance = stepsSound.CreateInstance();
soundEffectInstance.Volume *= 0.5f;
soundEffectInstance.Play();
```

How to use it? How to set speed of sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`SpeedOfSound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.speedofsound.aspx) is the value for the speed of sound... that is, how fast sound waves propagate. It does not control the *playback speed* (or thus, effective duration) of an individual sound. Instead, it alters how the Doppler effect of 3D sounds is perceived.

What you probably want is to change the sound's [`Pitch` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.pitch.aspx), although this has a limited range.

XNA does not natively support pitch-invariant time distortion of a sound, as far as I am aware.

Comment: how does it affect sound?